# Best way to remove duplicate words from each row in a mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, string

I have a mysql table, each row of which can have an arbitrary number of comma-delimmited words.  For example:

```
TABLE words
"test, dog, fun, yellow, quick, yellow"
"jogging, academic, fun, jogging, shoulder"
"shoulder, happy, flower, shoulder, shoulder"
```

I would like to remove the duplicate words in each row.  So for example, the above would become:

```
TABLE words
"test, dog, fun, yellow, quick"
"jogging, academic, fun, shoulder"
"shoulder, happy, flower"
```

(Note that I only need to remove the duplicates in each row, by itself.  I do not need to remove the duplicates between all rows.)

Any suggestions on the best way to accomplish this?  Is there a better way than SELECTing and then UPDATEing through the table one row at a time?

Thanks, in advance, for your help.

Comment: I think your database design needs some reworking.

Comment: @Anon: This table is for search fodder only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is better suited outside of SQL. It's not going to be pretty if you try to interrogate strings using a query. I recommend:

- `SELECT`ing each row
- performing an `$val = explode(', ',$column);`
- switch to `$val = array_unique($val);`, then
- `UPDATE`ing to the table with implode(', ',$val);`.

note: you can save yourself some time and do a `strcmp($orig,$new)` and only `UPDATE` if necessary.

Comment: Hate to say it, but for this situation -- yes. +1

Comment: as above.I also agree that the design needs review since it should not be storing a list of words if you need to search on maintain uniqueness between words. Normalisation, please! :)

Comment: Thanks - I was hoping there might be a more efficient way of doing this, but c'est la vie.  :)

Comment: @David - Respectfully I disagree.  In situations where a table is being used purely for search bait, I think this pattern is ok - so long as the same data exists in a normalized form elsewhere in the database.  Which it does.

Comment: @Travis: I don't think there is a use case for structuring data this way. If you're searching for individual words, searching the normalized data for exact matches (using an index) will be *much* faster than running fulltext searches. What exactly are you searching for?

Comment: @Travis - sounds like a longer conversation :) My point in this case is that while I'm not against using denormalisation to assist the database in certain cases (eg to avoid repeated calls to sum() queries) but in the case where it involves DB string searches I'd prefer to have single values to improve indexing. IMO etc, but as always the exact circumstances would dictate the exact solution. So I'm not saying I believe you're wrong, merely that I'd probably head in a different direction.

Comment: @Anon - I am interested in searching phrases, words, and word fragments.  If a search includes word fragments, in particular fragments that fall within the left and right boundaries of a word, then to my knowledge it's best (ie simplest) to use a fulltext.  Though if there are better ways I'd love to know about them.

Comment: @David - Thanks, your response is well taken.  :)

Comment: @Travis: You could break it out in to a specific words table, then use a tableA_words relational table. Doing a search against the words table for 'word%','%word%', or '%word' and getting their keys for filtration would be trivial.

Comment: @Brad - Appreciate the response, but not sure I follow.  Can you elaborate with an example?

Comment: @Travis: Clearly you're not searching phrases against this particular dataset, because deduplication would break that entirely. When it comes to words and word fragments, breaking it down based on word boundaries is still going to help a lot, even if you still need to do fulltext searches on a subset of those values.

Comment: @Anon - Sorry, you're right, no phrases in the above model.  However can you please clarify:  If I were to break strings down based on word boundaries, so that every row in the table is a single word, and then I run a fulltext search on those rows - am I gaining much in terms of performance?  (I didn't think I was, but would love to know if I am.)

Comment: @Travis: It depends on the database engine of course, but quite commonly yes. Shorter words mean you can build a more efficient fulltext index and fail faster when the word doesn't contain the search string. Though of course, actually benchmarking it is preferable to speculation.

Comment: @Anon - Good to know.  Appreciate the advice.  I will do some experimenting.

Comment: Avoiding 'like' searches should be avoided if possible too, although if you find they can't be avoided then having the '%' at the end of the like search can be better than '%word' or '%word%' depending on your database. IMo better not to worry and just avoid like searches if you can.

Comment: Back to Anon's last comment, _if_ you index the string column and _if_ you're using exact *case sensitive* (depending on the DB) string matches _then_ having a single word will be significantly faster. The down side to this is that it will be slower to add or update words due to the index, but (again IMO) this is easily offset in text searching since in general you add less words over time and spend more time searching.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's better way than SELECTing and then UPDATEing through the table one row at a time. As I know, SQL just don't support manipulating string like that. You must take a string out to remove duplicate, then insert it again in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure mysql version you use a bunch of number for a CROSS JOIN for each word then you just DISTINCT concat the broken words.It would help if you have a primary or unique key in case the rows are identicals.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.col, ', ', x.cifre), ', ', -1)) AS words
FROM t
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 1 + a.i + b.i * 10  cifre, b.i + a.i * 10  sute
    FROM (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) a
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) b
) x
ON (LENGTH(t.col) +1 - LENGTH(REPLACE(t.col, ', ', ''))) >= x.cifre
GROUP BY col
```

[FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e1f13/2)